# Comparing strings in python with < comparision operator

Tags: python

I am a novice in python and am trying to learn the basics. I found a weird behaviour with the python interpreter:

```
>>> 'Pp' < 'Pn' 
False      # --> expected p comes after n
>>> 'Pap' < 'Pbn'
True       # --> though a < b, p is not < n. How can this result as True?
```

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: It's alphabetical order.

Comment: In Lexicographical `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order`

Answer (score 4):

Why would you expect it to care that b > n? This is alphabetical sorting, like you would find in a telephone directory (if those still exist). You would expect to see them ordered like this:

```
Pap
Pb
Pbn
Pn
```

and that is indeed what Python returns.

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) :

The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

'Pp' < 'Pn' 
In this case first the first letters of both the string is compared as they are equal. so, it will compare the second letters as n appears first in the alphabets it must be less than p. As it violates the condition it returns False.

'Pap' < 'Pbn'
  Here in the same way first letters are compared as they are equal it will compare second letters of both the string as a appears first in the alphabetical order it is less than b. so the condition is satisfied and it breaks the loop and retuns True. 
If once the condition is satisfied it will return True and breaks . If it is not satisfied it will do the same until the end of the string.